# Using global variables instead of pushing values to next activity/view through segue

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, swift

This question applies to both iOS and Android development.

I've been using both development environments and with iOS there is a standard convention for transferring values through views/scenes using segues.

The same applies for Android where you 'put extra' values on to the Intent when switching activities.

My question is,

Why can't we just have a class in Java/Swift/Objective C which consists of global variables that can be accessed throughout all classes. This way we can simply edit a global variable and after switching views/activities we can access them once again.

I have already done this using iOS in one of my apps and saw no reason to do it any other way.

So why is this not standard or generally accepted.

Comment: Memory is a common issue on mobile devices.  By creating global variables that are accessible across activities/view controller you are holding onto memory that you may not need in every single activity/view controller.

Comment: If I was to create a hierarchy of classes corresponding to a controller, which handles a specific number of views/activities, could I not then create variables accessible by only the views I want, hence eliminating the memory problem? It just sounds easier and more controllable using these class variables. Not necessarily global variables in this case. I would like to be 100% convinced if I am to scrap global/class variables.

Comment: Yeah class variables are completely fine as long as they are instance variables.  If you manage your references properly then you  can share instance variables between classes as much as you want.  But its the static class variables that tend to stick around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using global variables you should consider following cases

1. How relevant are they to keep it in memory always.
2. You should worry about concurrent access and implement synchronisation
3. You should think about lifetime of each such global variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons global variables should be avoided when possible despite it being seemingly easier to accomplish some development tasks. This does not only apply to android/ios development but most other languages as well (especially object oriented languages).

Check out this link: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 0):

Having global variables is generally not advised beacause in industry where a lot of people work on the same app, having global variables creates a lot of confusions and logical errors that are really hard to debug.

So it is advised to avoid global variables and play within your own module which is assigned to you